# UniDrv User Interface Plugin: Unable to show the paper size field

Tags: windows, driver

The printer driver I must modify is for a roll-fed printer with custom paper sizes, and with an application that uses custom (application defined) size.

The `*Feature: PaperSize` is currently hidden from UI.
My task is to make it shown. But it refuses.

The hiding is happening in 2 places:

- in the gpd:

```
*Feature: PaperSize
{
    *rcNameID: =PAPER_SIZE_DISPLAY
    *DefaultOption: Size_4x6
    *ConcealFromUI?: TRUE      *% Removing this

    *Option: Size_4x6
    {
        *Name: "4 x 6"
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(1200, 1800)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(1200, 1800)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(0, 0)
    }
    ....
    *Option: CUSTOMSIZE
    {
        *Name: "CUSTOM SIZE"
        *rcNameID: =USER_DEFINED_SIZE_DISPLAY
        ...
    }
}
```

- in the UI plugin:

```
for (DWORD i = 0; i < pOemCUIPParam->cDrvOptItems; i++)
{
    VERBOSE("pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID %d\n", pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID);
    if (pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID == DMPUB_FORMNAME)
    { 
        VERBOSE("Sad story, this never happens\n");
    }
    else 
    // This is the original code. The part above is my intention to treat DMPUB_FORMNAME separately
    if ((pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID > DMPUB_FIRST) && (pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID < DMPUB_LAST))
    {
        pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].Flags |= (OPTIF_HIDE | OPTIF_EXT_DISABLED);
    }
}
```

Removing the `*ConcealFromUI?: TRUE` and running in debug mode, and displaying all `pOemCUIPParam->pDrvOptItems[i].DMPubID`,
I found that `DMPUB_FORMNAME` does not appear.

I can't find any examples, other than the Microsoft Windows Driver Samples, and am not able to determine why there is no `DMPUB_FORMNAME` value.

The only ones I get in my debugging are:
`DMPUB_DEFSOURCE, DMPUB_ORIENTATION, DMPUB_COPIES_COLLATE, DMPUB_COLOR, DMPUB_ICMMETHOD, DMPUB_ICMINTENT, DMPUB_NUP, DMPUB_PAGEORDER, DMPUB_NUP_DIRECTION` - I expected lots more.

I cannot determine if my gpd is incorrect, or if I must add something specifically for the forms to show. The orientation selector, which is not hiding despite of the above code which should hide it, does not require any code to be shown.

The driver is functional, and the paper sizes are available through the driver options, and in some software through page setup. But not in Print Preferences dialog.

What must I do to get the `DMPUB_FORMNAME` to show ?

Any suggestion pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use `*rcNameID:`  instead of `*Name:`  in the GPD form displayed name.

The actual problem: some forms had decimals, and strangely dots seem to not be supported in the form name. So, using a resource reference was needed for those specific forms. Strange that the forms did exist in the Server Properties (including the decimal ones) but were not forwarded to the UI.

Example: `*Name: "My 8.5x11"` is not supported, but I can still use it if I define it as a resource.